# Move instead of copy to PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, phphotolibrary

My iOS app records a video (in `NSTemporaryDirectory()/...`) and I want to save it to the camera roll.

This works fine but to save disk space I would like to **move** the file to the camera roll, **not copy** it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can save it to camera roll, then you can remove source file via [removeItemAtPath:error](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1408573-removeitematpath?language=objc) method of [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager?language=objc) when saving is completed.

Comment: but this needs double memory temporarily : copy then delete instead of move